# Некорректное отображение admin панели django

Tags: django, django-admin

Моя проблема заключается в том, что admin панель не отображается корректно. Несколько окон как бы наслаиваются друг на друга и работа с панелью становится не возможной. Случилось это с самого создания проекта. При этом со стилями вроде бы все хорошо. Очень был бы благодарен за любую помощь!

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('Вход.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('Главная.urls')),
    url(r'^Новости/', include('Новости.urls')),
    url(r'^Видео/', include('Видео.urls')),
    url(r'^Фото/', include('Фото.urls')),
    url(r'^Аудио/', include('Аудио.urls')),
    url(r'^Документы/', include('Документы.urls')),
    url(r'^О_нас/', include('О_нас.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-vs7bbhw5n5trc#9b76jp*7+v%&%ojpodampt5yze=jiy=ahc^z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Главная',
    'Вход',
    'Новости',
    'Видео',
    'Фото',
    'Аудио',
    'Документы',
    'О_нас',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Крылья_веры.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Крылья_веры.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

[image: Скриншот с проблемой]

Comment: Если создать новый чистый Django-проект с нуля — там будет такая проблема? Если нет — ищите разницу между чистым проектом и проблемным проектом

Comment: В том к сожалению и проблема, что новые проекты абсолютно также выглядят. Ничего не меняется.

Comment: Может, тогда проблема просто в вашем браузере?

Comment: А если другую версию django взять? У вас смотрю 3.2, хотя уже 4 вышла. Может 4 не трогать, но новейшую STL из 3 взять?

Comment: Сейчас кстати случайным образом заметил, что этот эффект исчезает, когда окно браузера уменьшать... Хотя это тоже не показатель того, что дело только в браузере.

Comment: Достаточно старая версия по причине поддержки моего хостинга только django 3 версии. Не хотелось бы менять его

Comment: Какой браузер-то хоть?

Comment: Злосчастный chrome..

Comment: Перепроверил на других браузерах и оказалось, что это проблема только лишь chrome... Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Возможно, почистьте кэш?

Comment: Вы просто не представляете, это помогло! Я даже не думал, что настолько простое решение этой проблемы. Огромное спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Решил такую проблему копированием недостающих css файлов, из project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css в project/static/css/admin
использовалась django 4.0.2